# On a slide guitar, how much is string tension important?

Tags: guitar, slide

I'm re-visiting slide guitar playing, and need to set up a guitar for that purpose. It's going to be quite different from my usual .008" set, and the action will obviously be much higher, so much so that it will be uncomfortable to play normally.

Would it be best to use a higher gauge string (thus more tension) or are thinner strings going to do a good job? Not so loose that they rattle on the fretwires, obviously!

Answer (score 2):

It's always been the case, the heavier the strings, the better the sound. Heavier strings need more tension, but idk whether it's *strictly* the extra metal or the extra tension responsible for that.
Personally, I can't use 8s, I just push them constantly out of tune. I use 'skinny top, heavy bottom' 10 - 52 on all my electrics.

Though they're probably still lighter than some of the early rock gods used, plenty of them would just whip out a slide & go for it, using exactly the same setup they did for regular playing. Increasing string tension, even if you don't raise the action, makes it less likely you'll travel the frets whilst playing slide - & still be able to play normally.

*In case this wasn't obvious, judging by comments…*
You don't need to turn one guitar into the equivalent action of a lap-steel just to use a bottle-neck.
Also 'going out of tune' is completely independent of this setup consideration.

Any excuse to play something by my all-time favourite rock god - Leslie West. This one sounds very much like he's splitting the playing 50/50 straight & slide, all of course on the same guitar he does the whole gig on - a short-scale Les Paul Junior.

Confirmed from [Guitar Player - Leslie West Decodes His “Mississippi Queen” Tone](https://www.guitarplayer.com/players/leslie-west-decodes-his-mississippi-queen-tone) he used a 10 top, in similar vein to Clapton, borrowing it from a set of banjo strings & shifting the rest down a place.

Comment: “the heavier the strings, the better the sound” – is certainly not a universally-accepted truth. And this isn't much of an answer regarding how string weight / tension matters for slide specifically. Going out of tune is, I'd say, much less of an issue with slide, because there's no need to play bends and the slide notes will have on-the-fly intonation anyway.

Comment: Only guitar in the house with 8s is my partner's strat… & it sounds like pants unless you ramp it through a hi-gain amp. I really don't like, or ever use, hi-gain amps or the sound they produce. Increasing string tension makes it far less likely you'll travel the frets on your slide, thereby increasing the chances the guitar will work for both slide & regular playing without need for further compromise. tbh, I'd never even considered going out of tune at all.

Comment: I am firmly in the heavy-lights camp also. I think 8s might not have enough resistance to bouncing and you'd be more likely to hit the frets, but as @Tetsujin suggests would be fine and it really doesn't require much adjustment. Of course the rare time I use a slide it is more of a David Gilmore 1969 than slide blues. The real trick is learning to keep the slide flat and not run an angle along the fret edges

Comment: I personally like heavier strings but it appears to be a matter of personal taste, since well-respected YouTube musicians (who also play very well) Rhett Schull and Rick Beato did some listening test videos and prefer 9s. See: https://youtu.be/42lF0ITBKHk?si=wx1LK_teJiNVAG0P